# Sqoop import with Hcatalog failled:java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import a table from mysql to hive and i getting this errors.

```
2023-01-09 07:05:51,198 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1673201919048_0006
2023-01-09 07:06:30,327 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1673201919048_0006 running in uber mode : false
2023-01-09 07:06:30,335 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2023-01-09 07:06:31,196 INFO metastore.HMSHandler: Opening raw store with implementation class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2023-01-09 07:06:31,198 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@2ba31591, with PersistenceManager: null will be shutdown
2023-01-09 07:06:31,199 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@2ba31591, with PersistenceManager: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager@2f9c843d created in the thread with id: 24
2023-01-09 07:06:31,280 INFO metastore.HMSHandler: Created RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@2ba31591
2023-01-09 07:07:13,181 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:13,301 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000009_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:13,311 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:13,343 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:21,192 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000005_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:21,211 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:21,218 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000008_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:27,629 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:27,644 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000007_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:27,683 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:31,363 INFO metastore.HMSHandler: Opening raw store with implementation class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2023-01-09 07:07:31,462 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@60ea2bb0, with PersistenceManager: null will be shutdown
2023-01-09 07:07:31,747 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@60ea2bb0, with PersistenceManager: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager@64d5b375 created in the thread with id: 27
2023-01-09 07:07:33,769 INFO metastore.HMSHandler: Created RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@60ea2bb0
2023-01-09 07:07:52,625 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:52,655 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:52,681 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000006_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:57,070 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000008_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:07:57,085 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000005_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:02,611 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000004_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:16,499 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000007_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:16,512 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:16,522 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000009_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:16,532 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:21,870 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:26,172 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000008_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:26,180 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:31,340 INFO metastore.HMSHandler: Opening raw store with implementation class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2023-01-09 07:08:31,341 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@1f6b9cfd, with PersistenceManager: null will be shutdown
2023-01-09 07:08:31,341 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@1f6b9cfd, with PersistenceManager: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager@1b540bc8 created in the thread with id: 21
2023-01-09 07:08:31,666 INFO metastore.HMSHandler: Created RawStore: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore@1f6b9cfd
2023-01-09 07:08:46,826 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000002_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:49,050 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1673201919048_0006_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportHelper.<init>(SqoopHCatImportHelper.java:88)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatImportMapper.setup(SqoopHCatImportMapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)

2023-01-09 07:08:51,248 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
2023-01-09 07:08:51,609 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop    ip=unknown-ip-addr    cmd=Done cleaning up thread local RawStore    
2023-01-09 07:08:51,612 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient: Closed a connection to metastore, current connections: -1
2023-01-09 07:08:52,296 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2023-01-09 07:09:11,748 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1673201919048_0006 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1673201919048_0006_m_000003
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

2023-01-09 07:09:12,907 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=26
        Killed map tasks=9
        Launched map tasks=34
        Other local map tasks=34
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1313721
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=1313721
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1313721
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1345250304
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
2023-01-09 07:09:13,020 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
2023-01-09 07:09:13,047 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 262.2367 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
2023-01-09 07:09:13,056 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
2023-01-09 07:09:13,061 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Import job failed!
```

this the command:
sqoop import -connect jdbc:mysql://master:3306/*** --username **** --password **** --query "select id,referrer,from_url,landing_page_url,url_title,platform_description,other_params,history from web_chat_text_ems_2019_07 where 1=1 and $CONDITIONS" --hcatalog-database itcast_ods --hcatalog-table web_chat_text_ems_ods -m 10 --split-by id

Thanks!

why have the errors and how to solve it.

Comment: Is the table has some uncommon data types like BLOB,CLOB, LONG etc.?

Comment: The type of data in the table(mysql) is int and text.and the data type of the table created in HIVE is int and string

Comment: what version of sqoop, hadoop and hive you are using? make sure all versions are compatible with each other

Comment: sqoop 1.4.7, hadoop 3.3.1 hive4.0.0-alpha-2,mysql8.0.And use the command     sqoop list-databases -connect jdbc:mysql://master:3306/ --username **** --password ****  is ok.